# OLS in Julia for Econometrics

Tags: julia

I am studying econometrics from coursera and I am trying to implement OLS in Julia, But I keep having this error:

```
UndefVarError: Cnsmr not defined

top-level scope@none:1
eval@boot.jl:368[inlined]
eval(::Expr)@PlutoRunner.jl:93
top-level scope@Local: 8
```

when I try to do an OLS analysis:

```
begin
    industries = ["Cnsmr", "Manuf", "HiTec", "Hlth", "Other"]
    for industry in industries
        # Check if the column exists in the DataFrame
        if industry ∈ names(df)
            # Define the linear regression model
            formula_str = string(industry, " ~ Mkt")
            model = lm(eval(Meta.parse(formula_str)), df)
    
            # Fit the model
            fit_model = fit(model)
    
            # Extract the intercept and its p-value
            intercept = coef(fit_model)[1]
            p_value = coef_pvalues(fit_model)[1]
    
            println("Industry: $industry")
            println("Alpha (Intercept): $intercept")
            println("Is statistically significant? ", p_value < 0.05)
            println()
        else
            println("Column $industry does not exist in the DataFrame.")
            println()
        end
    end
    
end
```

I checked if df contains Cnsmr column and it does.  Can you please help me understand my problem?

I tried manually checking if df contains such columns, and it does.

Comment: You can find OLS implemented in Julia here : https://github.com/mossr/BeautifulAlgorithms.jl#linear-regression